# Why is static variable checked for nil and then assigned?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

The following code is present in Apple's iOS development guides (found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CustomizingMasterView/CustomizingMasterView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH4-SW4)):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BirdSightingCell";

    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
    if (formatter == nil) {
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    BirdSighting *sightingAtIndex = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:sightingAtIndex.name];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[formatter stringFromDate:(NSDate *)sightingAtIndex.date]];
    return cell;
}
```

Why set formatter equal to nil then check if it's nil? In which case would it not be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`formatter` is a **static** variable, which is only initialized once.. So

```
static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
```

will be executed only once for multiple execution of this function.

In short, they are making sure to **reuse** the `formatter` object, instead of creating it every time.

So Regarding your question,

> In which case would it not be?

the formatter object will be `nil` only for the first execution of the function, so the code

```
 formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc];
 [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
```

will be only executed once.

For a change the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) on static variable is easy to read, and help you understand the concept. They use a C programming language example, but the concept is similiar in objective C.

Answer (score 1):

It's because it's `static`. So, the first time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called, the `formatter` will indeed be `nil` and will therefore be initialized as a valid `NSDateFormatter` with a `dateStyle` of `NSDateFormatterMediumStyle`. The next time this method is called, `formatter` will no longer be `nil`, and you won't need to initialize it again. It's just a convenient (albeit, apparently confusing if you're not familiar with the `static` qualifier) way of having a variable that is initialized only once.

Answer (score 1):

formatter is static, so that it will only be initialized for one time only. Thus, it may not be nil in the next time this function is called.

see here: http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/java-developers-guide-to-static-variables-in-objective-c.html